# How to delete item using Groupie RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, groupie

I am using [Groupie](https://github.com/lisawray/groupie) to populate my RecyclerView and I am trying to get a delete-button in my RecyclerView to work. I figured how to do it in my activity using the `setOnItemClickListener` but I want the listener to only be invoked when I click on the delete-button:

```
val adapter = GroupAdapter<ViewHolder>()
...
recycleview_my_cards.adapter = adapter
...

        //this works
        adapter.setOnItemClickListener { item, view ->
            val userCardItem = item as UserCardItem
            val id = userCardItem.userCreditcard.id
            if (id != null) {
                deleteCard(id)
            }
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.deleteCreditCard)?.setOnClickListener {
            //how should this be done?
        }
```